# Is RSS an option?

Tags: support, rss

I am an RSS junkie. My Google Reader has loads of RSS feeds and I actually read them. I looked but did not see an RSS feed for the questions for SQA. Since the user doesn't have to log in to view the questions, I was hoping it's an option. Is there an option for RSS and I am missing it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Safari browser, and I clicked the "RSS" widget before refresh and got this URL:

[feed://sqa.stackexchange.com/feeds](http://feed://sqa.stackexchange.com/feeds)

I added the feed to my google reader, and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for responding. That works great in my google reader as well.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried https://sqa.stackexchange.com/feeds ?

Comment: I didn't know that was an option. I am using Chrome & just did not see it anywhere. But yes, that works great in my Google reader. Thank you

Comment: You can see the relevant icons in the bottom-right of each page here and at sqa.stackexchange.com  (I use Chrome too)